# Composite Mode "Add" (and more)

Tags: java, java-2d, composite

For implementing colored lightning in my exercise-engine I need the composite mode ADD.

There is no mention of this mode (and many other commonly used like subtract, average, burn, etc...) here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html

I also don't find it by experimenting.

Since I am pretty new to Java I suppose I am doing something wrong.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

I prefer not doing it in software (mainly because I don't want to loose any hardware-acceleration, secondly because I don't know how).

Comment: I don't think you need any advanced image combining techniques here. Simple alpha blending should be adequate. Just use one of the OVER modes. If you look at the equations, you will see that all they do is add the two color values, with alpha applied.

Comment: SRC_OVER does not work for me. However: I am not 100% sure that my overall architecture is sound. I will verify this and get back with the result in a few hours.

Comment: I implemented it in software for testing (15x slower than compositing using Java-methods): I need to ADD color-components and SUBTRACT source-alpha from destination-alpha. I found no composite-method which implements this equation. However I managed to achieve the desired result: 1. fill with environment light (color), 2. "punch wholes" of desired alpha value with RadialGradientPaint and composite DST_OUT, 3. "fill wholes" with desired light-color and RadialGradientPaint and composite SRC_ATOP.

Comment: I don't want to question your motives, but do you really need to manipulate the alpha value in such a way? Don't forget that it is discarded once your image is rendered. It will only ever be used during composition. Perhaps you are seeing incorrect results due to alpha premultiplication (or a lack thereof). It might help to write the whole blending equation down, as AlphaComposite seems a bit peculiar.

Comment: @onitake: that's a perfectly valid question. unfortunately, I am 99.5% sure that I do, since my equation cannot be found in any alpha-composite rule I have found SO FAR (I hadn't had time to read into the link you've sent me - thx for that besides). my software algorithm works and produces an optically nice result - I am just not convinced I am doing it efficiently (as usual...)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, AlphaComposite cannot do the blending modes typically found in image editors. There are two Java2D libraries that provide extended [Composite](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Composite.html) implementations:

1. [JHLabs filters](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html)
2. [SwingX](https://swingx.java.net/)

Or if you are using JavaFX, it has them [out of the box](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/BlendMode.html)

Don't worry too much about the performance, they are pretty fast.

Comment: well, not exactly the answer i was hoping for, but thank you for ensuring me not doing something wrong.